# Next 14 - localStorage not working after refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, next.js13

```
'use client';
import {
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  createContext,
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react';

interface ColorsContextProps {
  color: 'blue' | 'green' | 'red' | 'orange' | 'violet';

  setColor: Dispatch<
    SetStateAction<'blue' | 'green' | 'red' | 'orange' | 'violet'>
  >;
}

interface ColorsProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const ColorsContext = createContext({} as ColorsContextProps);

export function ColorsProvider({ children }: ColorsProviderProps) {
  const [color, setColor] = useState<
    'blue' | 'green' | 'red' | 'orange' | 'violet'
  >(
    (global?.localStorage?.getItem('preferred_color') as
      | 'blue'
      | 'green'
      | 'red'
      | 'orange'
      | 'violet') ?? 'blue'
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('preferred_color', color);
  }, [color]);

  return (
    <ColorsContext.Provider value={{ color, setColor }}>
      {children}
    </ColorsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I have this code and my localStorage is not available until the client loads. So the state is always set to blue, can anyone know what to do?

I wanted the state to get the localstorage value

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use `localStorage` to init the state value because as you said `localStorage` is not available on the server side.

You can init the state with a default value and use an `effect` to update its value as soon as the app is loaded on client side.

```
  const [color, setColor] = useState<...>('blue');

  useEffect(() => {
    setColor(localStorage?.getItem('preferred_color') ?? 'blue');
  }, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    color,
    setColor: newColor => {
      setColor(newColor);
      localStorage?.setItem('preferred_color', newColor);
    }
  }), [color, setColor]);

  return (
    <ColorsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ColorsContext.Provider>
  );
```

Comment: Not working aswell

Comment: Did you set a value for the `preferred_color` item in your localStorage ?